# TabLayout containing recyclerview data erased on backPressed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-tablayout

Working with activity, tabLayout and fragments. While moving from activity containing tabLayout contains RecyclerView in its first Tab to fragment which displays data of one of the reclerView item. When user presses back button the recyclerView data is erased.
Trying to debug the code the source will not creating the tabLayout or refetching the data. No method is called on backPressed.

Class file code which contains the tabLayouts

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

@BindView(R.id.tvRouteName)
TextView tvRouteName;
@BindView(R.id.pager)
ViewPager viewPager;
@BindView(R.id.tabLayout)
TabLayout tabLayout;
private TabPagerAdapter adapter;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("All"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pending"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Complete"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // set route name to the route
    String routeName = SiconApp.getInstance().getRouteName();
    if (routeName != null && !routeName.isEmpty())
        tvRouteName.setText(routeName);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
}
}
```

All efforts applied. Tried changing the code from onViewCreated, onResume and refreshing tabLayout etc.

Image provided below to find out the total of amount in recyclerView

[image: CheckImage]

Comment: User `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: dude this is the correct answer. I was trying this from last 48 hours and you saved me

Comment: See comment is enough :)

Comment: yup right. Same mistake i got in adapter and i was trying to change that to adapter but unable to, so i didn't notice this here.

Comment: @Wizard if you have free time i want to know how to calculate the GrandTotal of amount in a recycler view, and to be displayed in the same activity containing the recycler view.

Comment: Sure, get values from `dataset` i.e `ArrayList` using for loop and make it `+=`. You're done.

Comment: @Wizard i just attached an image above to the asked question. the quantity can be changed dynamically and the amount is changed on the basis of quantity and GrandTotal on amount change. I have achieved this but on text change each time i am reading the whole array again and again. If you have any better approach to complete this.

Comment: In code two developer may have different ideas to complete the same task. Thats why i asked this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this answer as a reply of this comment above:

> The quantity can be changed dynamically and the amount is changed on the basis of quantity and GrandTotal on amount change. I have achieved this but on text change each time i am reading the whole array again and again. If you have any better approach to complete this.

First thing first, Its not good to do calculation in `OnTextChange()`. Instead you should think about to have a click event of some `widget`.
Widget could be some `button` or keyboard's `done` button.

Here is some other approach:-

- Try to open spinner - *pro is you can limit the quantity if you're providing maximum quantity*
- Open a `dialog` with an `editText` and done button, by clicking on `done` do make calculations.
  **[UPDATE 1]**
  Adding my idea about the calculation:-

  ```
  // Calculate GrandTotal for the very first time
  int grandTotal = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < mDataSet.size(); i++) {
      // addition of all the sub-totals
  }

  // Get an event of quantity change of recyclerview row - using dialogbox or spinner or anything
  // basePrice is price of 1 quantity
  // oldQuantity is before updating new quantity to model
  currowModel = mDataSet.get(position); // Assuming currModel as current dataset item
  grandTotal = grandTotal - (currowModel.getBasePrice() * currModel.getQuantity());
  currowModel.setQuantity(updatedQuantity); // Setting new quanity to model
  grandTotal = grandTotal + (currowModel.getBasePrice() * currModel.getQuantity());
  ```

**Happy coding!**

Comment: posting my code that i implemented at onTextChanged

Comment: CustomerInvoiceFragment.grandTotal = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < CustomerInvoiceFragment.listItemOrderAmount.size(); i++) {
                    CustomerInvoiceFragment.grandTotal += CustomerInvoiceFragment.listItemOrderAmount.get(i);
                }
                //
                CustomerInvoiceFragment.tvCustomerTotal.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.strRupee) + String.valueOf(Utility.roundTwoDecimals(CustomerInvoiceFragment.grandTotal)));

Comment: each time i enter some value to my editText the above code runs. From coding aspects i think this is not a good approach because this arrayList is being read multiple times.

Comment: Don't loop whole `arrayList` everytime. For loop will come for the very first time. Subtract and and add only affecting rows data from grandtotal. **Keep the record of quantity in your model class**.

Comment: i have record of all these in model but still the issue is grand total contains the old value added into it and i am a bit confused how to manage that.

Comment: Added my idea, Do update quantity via some actions, `OnTextChanged()` is bad approach.